# How to find a word in a document that may be written in different forms? (Python)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, nlp

I need to find the word "Judgment" or "Judgement" or "JUDGMENT" or "JUDGEMENT" or "J U D G M E N T" from a document or any permutation/combination of those characters in both upper/lower cases (in that particular order). Is there a regex function that could help me out?
The problem is, I am applying the code to different documents and every document contains a different form of that word. My code needs to recognize the word in all instances.

Comment: Show us your attempts to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use your question as a string. Because it has all the combination you want and try this with you other combination. Leave a comment if this [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) not worked.

```py
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile('(j[\s]*u[\s]*d[\s]*g[e|M|\s]*n[\s]*t)', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> string = """I need to find the word "Judgment" or "Judgement" or "JUDGMENT" or "JUDGEMENT" or "J U D G M E N T" from a document or any permutation/combination of those characters in both upper/lower cases (in that particular order). Is there a regex function that could help me out? The problem is, I am applying the code to different documents and every document contains a different form of that word. My code needs to recognize the word in all instances."""
>>> 
>>> pattern.findall(string)
['Judgment', 'Judgement', 'JUDGMENT', 'JUDGEMENT', 'J U D G M E N T']
```

Here is the visualization of above [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to preprocess your text data. Otherwise, it wouldn't be rational to do so considering the time-complexity of such regular expression, if even possible.

---

Permutation might be possible since the order of letters would remain the same, combination would be quite complicated, which would include words such as `get`, `gem`, `Meg`, and many others.

If you maybe want to have a very low boundary expression, maybe this expression would be OK to look into:

```
\b([judgment\s]+)\b
```

and here you can see how it would fail:

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gDaZDd/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/gDaZDd/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.